# Adding NSData attachment to Twitter as an image post

Tags: objective-c, image, twitter

Currently my app gives the option to save to device, or email, the latter attaching the image automatically to the mail, I am looking to add a post to twitter option, simply attaching the image and posting to Twitter, I have done this a few times with other apps, but cannot seem to get this one working.

Here is the process for email;

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
     MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
     mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

     [mail setSubject:@""];

     NSString* path =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/email.png"];
     [mSplashView SaveResultImage:path];

     [mail addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]  mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Attached image"];

     NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I made this image!", [UIDevice currentDevice].model];

     NSString* mailcontent =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br> %@ <br>", msg];
     [mail setMessageBody:mailcontent isHTML:YES];

     [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];

     [mail release];
}
```

I am struggling to see how I can use similar to attach the image to Twitter, I currently use this code, but it crashes when attempting to post;

```
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];

   NSString* path =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/email.png"];
    [mSplashView SaveResultImage:path];


    [twitter setInitialText:@"I made this image!"];
    [twitter addURL:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]];

    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {

        if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Thank you" message:@"Posted successfully to Twitter." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alert show];

        }
        if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:@"You Cancelled posting the Tweet." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alert show];

        }

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    };


}
```

Normally I could simply call `[twitter addImage:];`  but unfortunately it seems the image is not grabbed correctly without going through the processes above in the mail sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass NSData for -addURL: method.

If your image store on disk, you can create image with [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath] method. Next add it with -addImage:

Comment: Excellent thank you for your help, what I did was this,works well;
`NSString* path =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/email.png"];
    [mSplashView SaveResultImage:path];
    
   UIImage *new_image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    
    
    [twitter setInitialText:@"I made this image!"];
    [twitter addImage:new_image];`

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString* path =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/imgtweet.png"];
       [UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        //NSLog(@"path %@",path);
        UIImage *new_image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
        {
            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:self.txtContent.text];
            [tweetSheet addImage:new_image];
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Using Previous Answer,Thanks :)
Happy coding :)